# Elastix - how to insert custom field

Tags: asterisk, cdr, elastix

I have problem with Elastix 2.5.0. I need to put custom value to custom field in cdr table. At this moment i modified cdr_mysql.conf and add [aliases] and [columns]

```
[columns] 
alias miasto => miasto

[aliases]
miasto = miasto
```

I also make custom incoming context for inbound calls where i have working line

```
...
exten => s,n,Set(CDR(miasto)=Warszawa)
...
```

And my question is: Why Elastix doesn't put custom CDR to mysql table ?!

Answer (score 0):

First I need answer a call then CDR custom field will be putted